# Integrate GeckoView in Android

Tags: android, gecko, geckoview

I'm facing problem in file upload in webview in Kitkat(4.4).
As per https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220 it can't be done in 4.4 due to missing method in new version of webview.

Hence searched and found GeckoView(https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView) as alternative for webview.
I followed all steps specified at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView, still project is not running in emulator as well as android device.

I tried downloading and importing sample project Geckobrowser in https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView, but it gives compile time error for getCurrentBrowser() method.

I'm using Windows OS. Can anyone please guide me through, not able to know what i'm missing. I'll really great-full for any lead in correct direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must check cpu abi version, and change geckoview_library and geckoview_asset to match the abi.

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mobile/nightly/

From the link, you can download several kinds of geckoview library.

This is a sample.

```
[DIR]   latest-mozilla-central-android-armv6/   12-Dec-2013 11:50    -   
[DIR]   latest-mozilla-central-android-r7/  12-Dec-2013 11:56    -   
[DIR]   latest-mozilla-central-android-x86/ 12-Dec-2013 11:56    -   
[DIR]   latest-mozilla-central-android/ 12-Dec-2013 11:56    -
```

In each folder, download geckoview_library and geckoview_asset.

Comment: if would put my app into google play store, how many compiled apk I need?

Comment: @rChavz Three. One for a abi. armv6, armv7(r7), x86