# Workaround for file uploads on Android 4.4 using reflection

Tags: android, android-webview, webchromeclient

From Android 4.1 to Android 4.3, you could subclass `WebChromeClient` on Android and implement the following (hidden, thus no `@Override`) method:

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) { ... }
```

You would open a file picker in that method, and when your `Activity` receives the result in `onActivityResult(...)`, just call the single method that is available on the `ValueCallback<Uri>` instance with the file URI. That's it.

Unfortunately, this method was removed from the API in Android 4.4 and is not being called anymore.

Is there *any* way you can work around this, e.g. with reflection?

I mean, you could set an `onclick="..."` listener on the `<input type="file">` element in HTML, which would still be called.

After intercepting the `onclick="..."` callback in Java (maybe via `addJavascriptInterface(...)`) you could open a file picker as usual. But the problem is that there's no `ValueCallback<Uri>` instance available that you could send your result (the file that was picked) to.

Setting the `value="..."` of the `<input type="file">` in HTML manually is not possible, either, because it's read-only. But the `WebView` implementation itself can certainly write the value, obviously. So could you use reflection to set the value there or find another workaround?

I'm searching for a cleaner and more comfortable solution than detecting the `<input type="file">` click (e.g. via its `onclick="..."` listener) and doing the file selection and file upload manually from Java. Enabling file uploads *in the WebView*, as they should work, would be cleaner, certainly.

Comment: Well I think a lot of dev's want this in 4.4. Unfortunately no one seems to have an answer. There is one comment in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220, regarding adding an entry in proguard file,  have you tried that, no idea if it works, although  doesnt make a lot of sense anyway(not going the reflection way)

Comment: @Slartibartfast Thanks! This thread in the Google issue tracker doesn't have a solution, unfortunately. This is why I thought a more complex solution may be possible that wasn't covered there. The ProGuard hint is true, but only required if it works generally and you don't want ProGuard to break it. On 4.4, it doesn't work at all, so the ProGuard rule is useless.

Comment: Hello @MarcoW. Did you find an easier way to handle `<input type="file">` ? Crosswalk is about 40-50 mb, and the other WebView alternatives are not stable.

Comment: @osrl No, I'm afraid you either have to include Crosswalk or accept that users on Android 4.4.x don't have file uploads (which I did).

Comment: @MarcoW. Do you think ignoring 4.4.x users are a good choice? There are so many kitkat users. I think I will use `JavascriptInterface` choice, which is not a good choice either.

Comment: @osrl Only you can decide this for your own case ;) 36.1% of all users are still on KitKat: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: It's about %60 of my users :)

Comment: In 2018: forget all these shits and check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31606758/3063226

Comment: @Heitor Everybody knows the solution for versions above 4.4. If you don’t care about the [13.4%](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) that are still on 4.4, go ahead, that’s fine.

Comment: @caw that answer is supposed to deal from API 11 to 23, have you read it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a clean solution to do this this without using tricky Javascript codes and detectors. I'd recommend using a Webview alternative.

**Crosswalk**
I'd recommend this. It'll work similar to the official webview. It's open source and made by the same people behind [ChromeView](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview). They've got a great setup guide: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html

Check it out: https://crosswalk-project.org/

**Chromium Webview**

Also inspired by ChromeView. They claim to have integrated the same API's as the official webview for easy migration. But they indicate that the Webview still might be a bit unstable.

Check it out: https://github.com/mogoweb/chromium_webview

**GeckoView**

Made by Mozilla. Here's a [demo project](https://github.com/mfinkle/geckobrowser) that uses it. Mozilla warns: "This is not a drop webview replacement and very unstable", but it has [file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493626/integrate-geckoview-in-android)

Check it out: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

If you're open on using Javascript (perhaps usefull for others) try:

**Kitkat Webview**
It uses javascript to enable file upload in KitKat webview do this. The demo allows you to upload an image, but you should be able to edit it to fit your needs.

Check it out: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Kitkat-WebView

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of these alternatives and it's not as clean as using reflection (which might not be possible). But it's definitely a great general overview. By the way, "Chromium WebView" is a great idea (compatible API) but it describes itself as not ready for production. "KitKat WebView", on the other hand, is the least convenient solution and uses JavaScript, as you said. This is what I don't want, as described in the question, because *cannot* use real file uploads with that solution. You have to do it asynchronously via AJAX, for example.

Comment: @Marco W. Edited my answer to better match your question and your findings on Chrome Webview. Even though they indicate it might not be ready for production    (like to use it as a full webbrowser), it might be stable enough to use it for displaying simple webpages and upload forms. In all honesty I wouldn't say vanilla webview is the most reliable solution either ;)

Comment: beware that crosswalk adds a huge extra weight to your project (20 - 80mb) depending on your architecture. And Tint browser is a fork of Chromium Webview which doesn't seem to be working for postimg.com i just tested it on android 4.4.2